# sql skip if status exists in group of records

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to skip a set of records from my query if a certain type of record exists in a batch.

I have records like this

```
ORDER        STATUS
1234         X
1234         Y
1234         Z
1235         X
1235         Y
1236         X
1237         X
1237         Y
1238         A
1238         B
```

As you can see, an order goes through multiple stages (X, Y, Z, A, B). I want to select orders that have not hit certain status, i.e. Z or B. So from the table above, I should only select order numbers and status where status for that order have not gone to Z or B.

Appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: So you need `WHERE NOT EXISTS()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.order = t.order and t2.status in ('Z', 'B'));
```

If you just want the orders without these statuses, you can use aggregation:

```
select order
from t
group by order
having sum(case when status in ('Z', 'B') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE STATUS NOT LIKE('B') AND STATUS NOT LIKE('Z');
```

this will return all the records which have not hit the Status **B** or **Z**.